# Need extension controller for the following visual force page

Tags: sorting, apex-code, visualforce

To all I have complete the visualforce code to be provide the pagination for the account records in the table as my requirement but I am try to provide the sorting function on that table.

> so I want the extension controller to provide the sorting function
>   with the ascending and descending functionality(because I am new in
>   the extension controller)for my visual page. So keep it in mind my pagination function is also worked together in the sorting function.

My Page is followingly,

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accountvar">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="My Accounts" subtitle="Account List View"/>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock >
              <apex:pageMessages id="error" />

               <apex:panelGrid columns="7" id="buttons" >
               <!---<apex:pageBlockButtons>---->
                    <apex:commandButton reRender="error,blocktable,buttons" action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
                    <apex:commandButton reRender="error,blocktable,buttons" action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
                    <apex:inputHidden />
                    <apex:commandButton reRender="error,blocktable,buttons" disabled="{!!hasprevious}" action="{!First}" value="First"/>
                    <apex:commandButton reRender="error,blocktable,buttons" disabled="{!!hasprevious}" action="{!Previous}" value="Previous"/>
                    <apex:commandButton reRender="error,blocktable,buttons" disabled="{!!hasnext}" action="{!Next}" value="Next"/>
                    <apex:commandButton reRender="error,blocktable,buttons" disabled="{!!hasnext}" action="{!Last}" value="Last"/>
               <!---</apex:pageBlockButtons>--->
               </apex:panelGrid>

               <apex:pageBlockSection id="blocktable" >

                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountvar}" var="t">

                            <apex:column headerValue="AccountName" value="{!t.Name}"/ >                                                
                            <apex:column headerValue="BillingState/Province" value="{!t.BillingState}"/> 
                            <apex:column headerValue="Phone" value="{!t.Phone}"/>
                            <apex:column headerValue="Type" value="{!t.Type}"/>                   
                            <apex:column headerValue="Account Owner Alias" value="{!t.Owner.Name}"/>
                            <apex:column headerValue="Website" value="{!t.Website}"/>

                        <apex:inlineEditSupport event="onClick"/>


                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

               </apex:pageBlockSection>   


            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

For answer's thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question belongs to the Salesforce StackExchange, you will have more answers here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Please delete this one and create it on the Salesforce SE :)